PencilKit visionOS attachment works in Simulator, not on Vision Pro
I wanted to create a canvas view to draw on it that is attached to an entity in an Immersive Space, so I did a simple code to test it.  I can draw on the GraffitiView using the Simulator, but when I run the application on the Vision Pro headset, I can't get to draw on the canvas. I don't even see the pencil mark on the canvas when I point with my hand.
This is the code I'm using for the drawing canvas view:
struct GraffitiView: View {
    @State private var canvas = PKCanvasView()
    @State private var color: Color = .orange
    @State private var pencilType: PKInkingTool.InkType = .crayon
    @State private var colorPicker = false
    
    var body: some View {
        DrawingView(canvas: $canvas, pencilType: $pencilType, color: $color)
    }
}

struct DrawingView: UIViewRepresentable {
  @Binding var canvas: PKCanvasView
  @Binding var pencilType: PKInkingTool.InkType
  @Binding var color: Color

  var ink: PKInkingTool {
    PKInkingTool(pencilType, color: UIColor(color))
  }

  let eraser = PKEraserTool(.bitmap)

  func makeUIView(context: Context) -> PKCanvasView {
    canvas.drawingPolicy = .anyInput
    canvas.tool = ink
    canvas.isRulerActive = true
      canvas.backgroundColor = .init(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1.0)
    canvas.alwaysBounceVertical = true

    let toolPicker = PKToolPicker.init()
    toolPicker.setVisible(true, forFirstResponder: canvas)
    toolPicker.addObserver(canvas)
    canvas.becomeFirstResponder()

    return canvas
  }

  func updateUIView(_ uiView: PKCanvasView, context: Context) {
    uiView.tool = ink
  }
}

and this is the code in my Immersive View:
struct ImmersiveView: View {
    var body: some View {
        RealityView { content, attachments  in
            let entity = Entity()
            entity.position = [0.0, 1.0, -1.0]
            if let attachment = attachments.entity(for: "draw") {
                entity.addChild(attachment)
            }
            content.add(entity)
        } attachments: {
            Attachment(id: "draw") {
                GraffitiView()
            }
        }
    }
}

any idea of why could this not work on the headsets?

Currently, there is no official confirmation that the Apple Pencil is compatible with the Vision Pro.
Apple has not yet released any information about input methods for the Vision Pro beyond the controller that comes with it. If there is please share it with this thread.
